# conditional probability symbol ";"?

Tags: conditional-probability

[image]

Is it a conditional probability? Is  ";" the same thing as "|"? if yes, why the writter use ; rather than |?

Comment: I think $\lambda$ is more likely to be a parameter of function $f$.

Comment: Related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130869/

Comment: Is $\lambda$ the name of a random variable? If not, then this notation cannot possibly refer to a conditional distribution.